# Hapi/Joi validation of float()

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, hapi.js

I have the following JavaScript code to test out the Hapi/Joi validation functions:

```
var Joi = require('joi');
var schema = { free: Joi.Types.Number().float() };
var value = { free: 3.3333 };
var err = Joi.validate(value, schema); 

//err is set if value fails to validate against the schema
if (err) throw err;
```

The validation throws the error:

```
Error: the value of free must be an integer
```

I would like to know what I am doing wrong. I am using the current versions of Hapi and Joi.

Comment: Take a look at: https://github.com/spumko/joi/issues/112, Hopefully this will be fixed soon;)

Answer (score 30):

This is rather out of date now, but in case others happen on this, the syntax now is (accepting all numbers, including floats):

```
Joi.number();
```

or, if you want it to be required:

```
Joi.number().required();
```

Also, see [the docs](https://github.com/spumko/joi#number).

Comment: I would also use `strict()` — https://medium.com/east-pole/surprised-by-joi-35a3558eda30